# Vue 3 switch from text to input and enable typing in one single clic

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to use a clic edit vuejs comonent with switch from text-> input.

The process is I clic on the text it switch to the input html tag.
Good but then I need to re-clicl to enter text.

How can I proceed to enter text as soon as I click the first time ?

```
    <template>
  <el-input
    v-if="edit"
    v-focus=""
    type="text"
    :value="local"
    placeholder="place"
    @blur.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);
    "
    @keyup.enter.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);"
  />

  <p v-else="" @click="edit = true" >  {{ local }}</p>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],

  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
      local: this.value,
    };
  },

  watch: {
    value: function () {
      this.local = this.value;
    },
  },

  directives: {
    focus: {
      inserted(el) {
        el.focus();
      },
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What about considering using `contenteditable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have access to the DOM element to trigger the focus on it. To do this, add a the `ref` attribute to your input: `ref="inputField"`
And in you your script: `this.$refs.inputField.$el.focus();`

```
<template>
  <el-input
    v-if="edit"
    ref="inputField"
    type="text"
    :value="local"
    placeholder="place"
    @blur.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);
    "
    @keyup.enter.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);"
  />

  <p v-else="" @click="startEdit" >  {{ local }}</p>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],

  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
      local: this.value,
    };
  },

  watch: {
    value: function () {
      this.local = this.value;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    startEdit() {
      this.edit = true;
      this.$refs.inputField.focus();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-template-refs.html

Comment: Not working neither , I think its due to : "$refs are only populated after the component has been rendered. It is only meant as an escape hatch for direct child manipulation - you should avoid accessing $refs from within templates or computed properties." => I made a workaround  by adding "    @mouseover="this.$refs.inputField.focus()"   " in the input tag

Comment: @SylvainPage it could work if you replace the `v-if` with the `v-show` and would then of course need to use one of them for the `<p>`

Comment: Oh, and if you anyway use the mouseover, you don't need the ref: `@mouseover="$event.target.focus()"` should work as well